# Como valido un string vacio?

Tags: c++, string

Estoy intentando hacer un ciclo que lea una cadena mientras no sea vació si cumple que no contiene ningún carácter pues se sale del ciclo; pero no lo he podido conseguir se queda un bucle y nunca se sale, he aquí mi código:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    string nombre;
    cout<<"ingrese una palabra "; cin>>nombre;
    while (nombre[0] !='\0'){
        cout<<nombre<<endl;
        cout<<"ingrese una palabra "; cin>>nombre;
    }
}
```

Mi problema esta en la condición del while `(nombre[0] !='\0')` que aparentemente no lo lee por alguna razón.

Porque no cumple esta condición?

Gracias.

Comment: Intenta `while (nombre[0] !=''){`

Comment: @alanfcm no me funciona por error de sintaxis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Mi problema esta en la condición del `while (nombre[0] !='\0')` que aparentemente no lo lee por alguna razón.

Tienes **problemas** si confías en esa condición.

---

Si el `std::string` está vacío no tendrá elementos, **ningún** elemento. Así que accediendo al primer elemento de un `std::string` vacío estás provocando un [comportamiento indefinido](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comportamiento_indefinido). Por ello podría ser que *se quede en bucle y nunca se salga*, o podría lanzar un error en tiempo de ejecución, o podrían invocarse [demonios que saldrían disparados de tus fosas nasales](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html).

El valor es leído, pero hemos descrito en el párrafo anterior será un valor indeterminado que posiblemente no sea casi nunca `'\0'` y en consecuencia casi nunca salga del bucle pese a que el `std::string` esté efectivamente vacío.

---

Una vez descrito el problema con el que te encuentras, pasemos a las soluciones. Si consultamos la [documentación de `std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string#capacity) vemos que dispone de varias funciones relativas a su capacidad:

- [`empty`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/empty): Comprueba si la cadena está vacía.
- [`size`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size), [`length`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size): Devuelve la cantidad de caracteres almacenados.
- [`max_size`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/max_size): Devuelve la cantidad máxima de caracteres que la cadena puede almacenar sin superar los límites de la librería o la implementación.
- [`reserve`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/reserve): Reserva memoria para almacenar más caracteres.
- [`capacity`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/capacity): Devuelve la memoria reservada para esta cadena, tanto si contiene datos como si no los contiene.
- [`shrink_to_fit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/shrink_to_fit): Reduce la memoria reservada por la cadena para que sea igual a la memoria que contiene datos.

En tu caso sólo son relevantes las funciones `size`, `length` y `empty`, que podrías usar de la siguiente manera:

`size`

```
while (nombre.size()){
    cout<<nombre<<endl;
    cout<<"ingrese una palabra "; cin>>nombre;
}
```

Los valores enteros son convertibles implícitamente a condición booleana siendo un valor `0` interpretado como `false` y cualquier otro valor interpretado como `true`; así pues: si `size` devuelve un valor diferente a `0`, permanecerá en el bucle, sucede exactamente lo mismo con:

`length`

```
while (nombre.length()){
    cout<<nombre<<endl;
    cout<<"ingrese una palabra "; cin>>nombre;
}
```

Finalmente, podemos saber si está vacío también con la función `empty`, pero nos requiere invertir la comprobación (ya que queremos que el bucle siga mientras no esté vacío):

`empty`

```
while (!nombre.empty()){
    cout<<nombre<<endl;
    cout<<"ingrese una palabra "; cin>>nombre;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Para saber si un objeto de tipo `std::string` está vacío tienes a tu disposición varias opciones:

- `length`: Este método te devuelve el número de caracteres. Si el objeto está vacío la longitud será cero:

  ```
  std::string test = /* ... */
  if( test.length() == 0 )
    std::cout << "Cadena vacia";
  ```
- `size`: Este método es equivalente a `length`. La existencia de `size` se justifica para que `std::string` se pueda utilizar con funciones propias de contenedores (`std::vector`, `std::set`, etc...)
- `empty`: Este método devuelve un booleano que indica si el objeto está vacío o no... simple y llanamente hace exactamente lo que tu pides.

  ```
  if( test.empty() )
    std::cout << "Cadena vacia";
  ```
- Iteradores: Vale, no es la forma más ortodoxa de hacerlo pero ya puestos es otra forma diferente de verificar que la cadena está vacía:

  ```
  if( test.begin() == test.end() )
    std::cout << "Cadena vacia";
  ```

Answer (score 3):

La manera mas sencilla de hacerlo es `Elnombredetustring.empty()` poniendolo es algun `if` por ejemplo:

```
if(Elnombredetustring.empty())
{
  cout<<"Esta vacio"
}
```

Y con tu pregunta de porque la manera en que tratas de hacerlo no funciona es porque para que funcione asi como lo muestras:

```
while (nombre[0] !='\0'){
        cout<<nombre<<endl;
        cout<<"ingrese una palabra "; cin>>nombre;
    }
```

Quiere decir que nombre tiene como valor 0 no que sea null es decir tendrias que igualar el string al char de 0 pero eso no quiere decir que esté vacio.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes probar con TextIsEmpty,

```
int main(){
    string nombre;
    cout<<"ingrese una palabra "; cin>>nombre;
    while (nombre.TextIsEmpty()){
        cout<<nombre<<endl;
        cout<<"ingrese una palabra "; cin>>nombre;
    }
}
```

o ponerlo con un valor definido que seria cero

```
   int main(){
        string nombre;
        cout<<"ingrese una palabra "; cin>>nombre;
        while (strlen(nombre) == 0){
            cout<<nombre<<endl;
            cout<<"ingrese una palabra "; cin>>nombre;
        }
    }
```

Comment: nombre.TextisEmpty no me funciona, que podria ser?

Comment: No funciona porque `TextIsEmpty` no existe.

Answer (score -1):

Pruedes probar poniendo `nombre.IsEmpty()` en el if lo cual devuelve un true o false dependiendo si la cadena esta vacía o no.
También puedes probar usar `strlen(nombre) == 0`, lo que hace strlen es contar el numero de indices del string (o el largo del string).
Espero te sirva.

Comment: Para esos necesito una librería? me falla el código por sintaxis.

Comment: `strlen` no funciona con `std::string` ...

Comment: La función `IsEmpty` no forma parte del objeto `std::string` de [tag:c++].